# Changing the labels on Matplotlib graphs (for example to Muli)

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

So I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Following should supposedly set the font correctly:
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Muli'] + plt.rcParams['font.serif']

# create data
size_of_groups=[12,11,30,3]


colors = ['#F92969','#FACA0C','#17C37B','#D9DFEB']

# Create a pieplot
my_pie,_,texts = plt.pie(size_of_groups,radius = 1.2,colors=colors,autopct="%.1f%%",
textprops = {'color':'w',                                                                                           'size':15,                                                                                                'weight':'bold'}, pctdistance=0.75, labeldistance=0.7) #pctdistance and labeldistance change label positions.


plt.setp(my_pie, width=0.6, edgecolor='white') 
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.show()
```

However, running this code doesn't get the right font (Muli). I can't place what I'm doing wrong:
[image: img]

Same applies for making the labels through the `plt.text` method.

The following code generates bar charts:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size_of_groups=[12,11,30,3]

colors = ['#F92969','#FACA0C','#17C37B','#D9DFEB']

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
plt.rcParams['font.serif'] = ['Muli'] + plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 15



plt.bar(height=size_of_groups,x=['a','b','c','d'],color=colors,width=0.95,label=['1',2,3,4]) #pctdistance and labeldistance change label positions.

# Setting the font to what I want it to be (Muli), using plt.text to place labels:

for v,i in enumerate(size_of_groups):
    if i > 5:
        plt.text(v-0.05,i-2.75,str(v),color='white',fontweight='bold',fontdict=None)
    if i <= 5:
        plt.text(v-0.05,i+0.8,str(v),color='gray',fontweight='bold',fontdict=None)
```

Once again, I get a very pretty chart, but not quite the right font:

[image: img2]

So my question is what it is exactly that I seem to be missing that is making it so I'm not seeing the font I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of the fonts you have installed you can do

```
import matplotlib.font_manager
sorted({i.name for i in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist})
```

if the font you want (Muli) is not there then track down your fontlist file (for me this is `~/.matplotlib/fontlist-v300.json`) and delete it. Try the above command again and see if it has now appeared.

Also you probably mean to have

```
plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['Muli'] + plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']
```

(`sans-serif` rather than `serif`)

Doing this and running your code I get
[image: the result]

For more detailed information about your fonts try

```
sorted([i for i in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist], key=lambda i: i.name)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the point in the right direction! My only problem now is that the "weight" (Boldness) of the font can't seem to be changed. It seems to be stuck at a semi italic-ish font, whereas the variation I'm after is bold.

Comment: @Yeahprettymuch if you try the command I've added to the edit I suspect that the filenames for Muli contain "VariableFont" in them? If this is the case then I think you need the static version of the font you want to use

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure you have muli installed as a system font.